# Outer Measure Does Not Generally Extend Inducing Function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X\neq\varnothing$; $\mathcal E\subseteq\wp(X)$; $\varnothing,X\in\mathcal E$; $\rho:\mathcal E\to[0,\infty]$; and $\rho(\varnothing)=0$. I want to convince myself that $\mu^*|_{\mathcal E}\neq\rho$, where $\mu^*:\wp(X)\to[0,\infty]$ is defined by

$$\mu^*\left(E\right)=\inf\left\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty\rho\left(A_j\right):E\subseteq\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\text{, where }A_j\in\mathcal E\text{ for all }j\in\mathbb N\right\}.$$

I tried letting $X=\{a,b\}$, $\mathcal E=\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\},X\}$, $\rho(\varnothing)=\rho(\{a\})=\rho(\{b\})=0$, and $\rho(X)=1$. Then $\mu^*(X)=0\neq1=\rho(X)$. Is this a valid counterexample?

I know that this would hold if $\rho$ were a premeasure on an algebra $\mathcal E$.

Are elements of $\mathcal E$ $\mu^*$-measurable?

For this, I tried letting $X=\mathbb Z$; $\mathcal E=\wp(X)$; $\rho(\varnothing)=\rho(X)=0$; $\rho(E)=1$ whenever $E$ is a nonempty, proper subset of $X$; and $E=\{0\}$. Then

$$\mu^*(E\cap X)+\mu^*(E\cap X^c)=\mu^*(E)+\mu^*(\varnothing)=1\neq0=\mu^*(X),$$

which implies that $X$ is not $\mu^*$-measurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be very intuitive that $\mu^*|_\mathcal{E}$ is not necessarily $\rho$. The example you gave is valid, and here is another. Let $X = \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{E} = X$. Define $\rho(\emptyset) = 0$ and $\rho(X) = \infty$. Then $\mu^*(X)$ could be many different things based on $\rho$ defined on other subsets. And since $\rho$ has no structure necessarily such as countable additivity, we can have many different values of $\mu^*(X)$. For example, if we define $\rho(\{1,3,5,7,\dots\}) = 1$ and $\rho(\{2,4,6,\dots\}) = .1$, and $\rho$ randomly on other subsets, then $\mu^*(X) \le 1.1$. The point is, we know nothing about $\rho$; it could be anything!

The example you gave showing the elements of $\mathcal{E}$ are not necessarily $\mu^*$ measurable is valid.